# How to add the AEM search component in header and display search results in the main content?

Tags: aem

I am working on AEM search component. I overlaid this component and added that in the header part of my page. But I need to get the search results in the main content of the page. How do I do that? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What did you try ? And did you check the sample search implementation in geometrixx ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could refer to the way the search component has been setup with Geometrixx-Outdoor Site

- Open en.html and enter design mode
- Check the configuration on the search box, you will see Search Path configured
- What this component does it that it appends the search text to this path and calls a redirect to it
  [image: Search Configuration]
- Next open up this page `/content/geometrixx-outdoors/en/toolbar/search`, here the search component is dropped and configured. This component is responsible for displaying the search results as well as accepting new search terms. This component script can be found at `/libs/foundation/components/search/search.jsp`

[image: Search page - results]

- Also look here - `/etc/designs/geometrixx-outdoors/jcr:content/page/search`, this is where the design configuration for the search configured in header is stored

So effectively there are two components -

- `/apps/geometrixx-outdoors/components/page/search` placed in header
- `/libs/foundation/components/search` placed on search result page

Comment: Sure! I have one more question regarding this. Though It works, But I am not sure where do we give the path of "/libs/foundation/components/search" component in "/apps/geometrixx-outdoors/components/page/search" component.

Comment: In short, how the mapping happens between these two components?

Comment: Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Components are not aware of each other. That said when your component in header is used for search all it does it redirect to the search page that has `/libs/foundation/components/search` component dropped on it.
This component reads the query parameter passed `q` and displays the search result.

Comment: The search page actually is not aware of the search box in header

Comment: Thanks a lot Ameesh for the explanation :)